# cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state') vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

Am trying to create a central store to store my data and fecth it from the store but am getting an undefined error

am using "vuex": "^4.1.0" and "vue": "^2.6.12",

I have the files working but when i add the computed property i get the error

store.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from 'vuex';
Vue.use(Vuex);
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        products: [
           
        ]
    }
});
```

Test.vue

```
<template lang="en">
    <div>
        <h2>Test list</h2>

        <ul>
            <li v-for="product in products">
            {{product.name}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    computed: {
        products(){
            return this.$store.state.products;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

App.js

```
require('./bootstrap');
import Vue from 'vue';
import vuetify from './vuetify';
import {store } from './store/store.js'
require('./routes') 

const app = new Vue({
    store,
    el: '#app',
    vuetify
});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Changed to vuex 3 gave it some minutes to think and now working

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

you need to use Vuex 3, which works with Vue 2:

https://v3.vuex.vuejs.org/

Comment: "vuex": "^3.0.1" installed but no change